# php resume ftp upload with curl multi

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I can't seem to resume an FTP upload using curl. It always appends the full local file to the partially uploaded remote file, resulting in the remote file being larger then the local file.

I am wondering if I have missed an option or if `curl_multi` has anything to do with it?

`$resume = true`

`$filesize` is the current size of the remote file in bytes, fetched using a separate curl ftp request.

I have tried with `CURLOPT_FTPAPPEND` option on and off.

Any help would be great as I am banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out :)

```
...

$ch[$i] = curl_init();

$file = fopen($local_file, 'rb');

if ($resume)
{           
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, $filesize);

        // move file position forward to resume
        fseek($file, $filesize);
}

curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$ftp['user']}:{$ftp['pass']}");
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($local_file));

curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);

...
```

**UPDATED**

Since hours of googling didn't help, I came up with a simple work around.

There are not many posts on using curl to resume an upload so I hope this helps someone else save time.

It is just one line using `fseek()`, but that is usually the case ;)

Comment: I found a work around but could someone tell me why it was not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Since hours of googling didn't help, I came up with a simple work around.

There are not many posts on using curl to resume an upload so I hope this helps someone else save time.

Use `fseek()` to move file position before calling `curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);`

...

```
$ch[$i] = curl_init();

$file = fopen($local_file, 'rb');

if ($resume)
{           
        curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_RESUME_FROM, $filesize);

        // move file position forward to resume
        fseek($file, $filesize);
}

curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_SFTP);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$ftp['user']}:{$ftp['pass']}");
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_INFILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch[$i], CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($local_file));

curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch[$i]);

...
```

Comment: how to check $resume? How do we know that connection interrupted and upload should progress form the resume?